# update the progressBar value from emitted signal

Tags: python, pyqt5, signals-slots, qthread, qtimer

getting the CPU percentage from psutil and display it on a progress bar.
i was able to display the value of the CPU percentage but it's not updating.
i have a file from QT designer called Progress i convert it using pyuic5 to py file and import it in the main file called cpuprogress.py, also i created a python file called sysinfo to get the value of CPU percentage and import it to the main file.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import  (QWidget, QApplication)
from progress import Ui_Form
import sysinfo


class MyTest(QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MyTest, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.threadclass = ThreadCLass()
        self.threadclass.start()
        self.threadclass.change_value.connect(self.updateProgressBar)
    def updateProgressBar(self, val):
        self.progressBar.setValue(val)

class ThreadCLass(QThread):
    change_value = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(ThreadCLass, self).__init__(parent)
    def run(self):
        while 1:
            val = int(sysinfo.getCPU())
            self.change_value.emit(val)

a =QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QWidget()
app = MyTest()
app.setupUi(window)
app.show()
sys.exit(a.exec_())
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/800MM.png)

Comment: Uhm, I see that you are doing `setupUi` twice, one in the class, and another one when starting the application. Try removing that last one.

Comment: wow it worked thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

### tl;dr

The problem is that you called `setupUi` twice, and the second time it was using another widget as argument.

### Why doesn't it work?

When you generate a file with pyuic, it actually creates a class, based on Python's `object` type. That class doesn't do anything on itself, is just an "interface" to load the elements of the ui in a "pythonic way".

If you try to open one of those files (which should **never** be edited!), you'll see something like this:

```
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(Form)
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 24)
        # ...

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        # things related to the localization of the ui
```

The official guide on [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) reports as a first example that actually does *nothing*, besides showing the window.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from ui_form import Ui_Form

# create an instance of the base class
window = QWidget()
# create an instance of the Ui "builder"
ui = Ui_Form()
# apply the ui to the base class created before
ui.setupUi(window)
```

The last step is the most important to understand: look carefully to what object the `setupUi` method belongs, and its argument, then go back to the contents of the file created with pyuic:

```
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(Form)
```

`Form` is the QWidget instance created before ("window"), while obviously `self` refers to the instance of `Ui_Form`; let's translate the variables with the name of the instancies they represent:

```
    def setupUi(ui, window):
        window.setObjectName("Form")
        ui.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(window)
```

In the example at the beginning it means that, while `window` is displayed with its children widgets, they are *not* attributes of the instance: there's no `window.progressBar`.

The second example in the documentation shows the "single inheritance" method, that allows the implementation of interactions between widgets (the "logic"). I'll use the class names as I did above:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from ui_form import Ui_Form

class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
```

Now `ui` is an attribute of the `window` instance; let's "translate" `setupUi` once again, assuming that now "self" is the instance of MyWidget that is being created:

```
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(window.ui, window):
        window.setObjectName("Form")
        window.ui.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(window)
```

This means that now you can have access to the widgets from the window instance, but only through `self.ui` (as in, *window.ui*).

Now, let's see the multiple inheritance approach, which is very similar:

```
class MyWidget(QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)
```

In this case, MyWidget inherits from the methods and attributes of **both** Qwidget *and* Ui_Form. Let's translate it again (note the class):

```
class MyWidget(object):
    def setupUi(window, window):
        window.setObjectName("Form")
        window.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(window)
```

This approach makes all widgets as direct attributes of the instance (`self.progressBar`, etc), and I usually suggest it as it's more direct and simple (it often happens that you try to access a widget and forget that `ui` prefix, with this method it doesn't happen).

---

### Now, finally, your problem.

```
window = QWidget()
app = MyTest()
```

`setupUi` is called in the `__init__` of MyTest, which means that `app` has an attribute called `progressBar`, which at this point should be "visible" as soon as we call `app.show()`.
You also created another widget, though (`window`), and used `setupUi` using *that* as parameter:

```
app.setupUi(window)
```

Let's translate it one last time (to avoid confusion, let's change the name of the "window" QWidget you created by mistake):

```
    def setupUi(app, otherWindow):
        otherWindow.setObjectName("Form")
        app.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(otherWindow)
```

As you can see, now you've "overwritten" the `app.progressBar` attribute, but that progress bar is actually a **new** one, and it is a child of `window` (which you never show).

The updateProgressBar function then will successfully modify the value of the progress bar, but *not* the one you see.

Finally, there's also another way of using ui files, and it is through the `uic` module, which can directly load ui files.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic

class MyTest(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None)
        super().__init__(parent)
        uic.loadUi('mywindow.ui', self)
```

This approach as a big advantage on the other: you don't have to create files with pyuic anymore, and it behaves exactly as the multiple inheritance method, so you can use `self.progressBar` as you did before.